# `require': cannot load such file - Running ruby from bash script

Tags: ruby, service, centos

I am trying to run a ruby script as a service on my centos machine. I can run the ruby script direct from the command line and from a bash file without issue.

However, when I try to run it as a service via /etc/init.d I get the error `'require': cannot load such file` -- somegem.

```
#! /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby
# encoding: utf-8

require "somegem"
```

I have created an init.d script and placed that in /etc/init.d/

```
#!/bin/sh
# monitor_endpoint
# chkconfig: 2345 20 80

# Source function library.
. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions

#Define variables
prog="monitor_endpoint"
exec=/home/user/Workspaces/test/bin/test.rb
echo $exec

start() {
    echo -n $"Starting $prog: "
    # use daemon to start the service
    daemon $exec &
    retval=$?
    echo
    return $retval
}

etc...
```

Would this be a problem with my gems installation path?

Any help would be much appreciated as this is my first attempt at running a ruby script in this way. Thank you.

Comment: What account is the script running under when it runs via the daemon? Maybe output `whoami` at the beginning of your script to check?

Comment: whoami returns root in the init.d script. Why does this behave diffrerently and what can I do to remedy this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is in your environment (the env vars).
run

```
env
```

in the normal environment and after that run it from the init script and pipe the output to a file.

look at the differences.

GOing to guess you are missing all the ruby specific stuff(GEM_PATH and all)

Comment: You are correct, env shows that I do not have ruby or gem in paths. What are my options here? How to I add these to the root path or conversely run the script as the current user? My aim is to have a transparent service that will work whoever is logged in.

Comment: You could log in as root and install the needed gems. Normally people have problems because they do the opposite, they install their ruby stuff as root or `sudo` and then can't find it under their profile. You want to give the root profile the gems it needs to run. Are you using anything like rbenv or rvm?

Comment: one option is to just setup the path before running the commands. Copy the paths you have in the normal env and setup exports. Installing the gems as root will not help if you don't have the path correctly setup. Another option is to source rvm or rbenv (or whatever you are using) before the execution.